# Nuances of meaning between "nos patients de l'étranger" and "nos patients étrangers"

Tags: choix-de-mot

> (1) Certains de nos patients ***de l'étranger*** choisissent ..., d’autres préfèrent ..., et il y en a qui ...
>
> (2) Certains de nos patients ***étrangers*** choisissent ..., d’autres préfèrent..., et il y en a qui ...

I wasn't sure how to accurately express the nuances of:

> patients who ***come from abroad*** to Japan solely for the purpose of seeking treatment at our clinic

as opposed to:

> ***non-Japanese*** patients at our clinic who ***already live in Japan***

The 1st phrase sprang to mind on the spot, but now I wonder how the 2nd phrase compares. How would you contrast these two ideas?

Comment: Our foreign patients and our patients from abroad. Same difference as in English.

Comment: I would interpret both of these (at least their English counterparts, as given by @Lambie) to mean patients coming from abroad just for treatment. It might just be me, but I don’t view people who live in a country as being “foreigners” to that country & I doubt if a medical facility would feel the need to make distinctions based on whether a patient was a native or a non-native resident. Keeping data (preferences) on patients coming from abroad just for treatment, however, would make sense, which leads me to interpret both versions as referring to foreign patients just seeking treatment.

Comment: @PapaPoule Good point! Would _‘en provenance de l'étranger’_ more clearly state that the mesage is intended not to immigrants (regardless of their national status), but to people coming from outside of Japan in order to visit the clinic? Somewhat similar to the way airports make the difference: _‘Les voyageurs en provenance de l'étranger sont priés de...’_.

Comment: @Feelew Oui, c’est pas mal, ça et en plus votre référence  aux aéroports me fait penser aussi aux  «voyageurs internationaux» et puis  aux [«patients internationaux»](http://www.anadolumedicalcenter.fr/pacients-internationales/).

Comment: @PapaPoule This is very good! Especially that ‘patients internationaux’ is clearly a one-way label (those that come from the outside), whereas ‘voyageurs internationaux’ could be either inbound or outbound, or even simply in transit. Also, the wording itself seems a lot more welcoming (since it avoids the psychological barrier set up form using a word like ‘étranger’).

Comment: @Feelew Very nice description of how changing just one word can render an utterance kinder, gentler, … more welcoming. I had considered throwing in the general notion of “being more politically correct” in my initial comment, but decided not to because so many people (ironically, imo) take/fake offense and bristle at that general notion of decency.  Getting specific, as you did with “more welcoming,” however, makes it harder for the “anti-PC” crowd to hide their true colors and what it is that really offends them.

Comment: @PapaPoule Hi. In recent years, we see a tremendous surge in the number of patients from aboard (who come to Japan for a one-off occasion, in a manner of speaking, in order to have a specific kind of operation that we specialise in. I often hear from European patients (especially from Switzerland) that the costs of the equivalent treatment in their own country amount to twice or even three times as much, making a possible $10,000 difference in total. It's for this reason that I needed to compare these two types of patients in saying this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Certains de nos patients de l'étranger...

→ Dans cette phrase *étranger* est un nom qui désigne un lieu. Étranger c'est ce qui n'est pas le pays d'où je parle. Une phrase qu'on peut lire en ce moment dans la presse française :

> Les Français de l’étranger ont voté samedi et dimanche pour le premier tour des législatives.(Par exemple [sur 20 Minutes](http://www.20minutes.fr/elections/legislatives/2080843-20170606-legislatives-apprend-vote-francais-etranger-scrutin-11-juin))

→ Il s'agit des Français qui résident hors de France. Dans ta phrase, il s'agit de patients, on peut éventuellement comprendre que les patients viennent de l'étranger, qu'ils sont ou non japonais, mais on peut aussi comprendre qu'il s'agit de patients qui résident hors du Japon, et ils peuvent être japonais ou non.

Donc pour éviter toute ambiguïté il vaut mieux employer la deuxième phrase.

> Certains de nos patients étrangers choisissent...

→ où *étranger* est un adjectif. Les patients sont étrangers au Japon, ne sont donc pas de nationalité japonaise mais résident en ce moment au Japon.

Si tu dis :

> Nos patients venant de l'étranger...

c'est tout aussi ambigu qu'en anglais car on ne sait pas si les patients sont japonais ou non.

Comment: Pourrait-on aussi dire *‘nos compatriotes **à** l'étranger’?* (c'est un peu hors-sujet, je sais, *‘nos patients à l'étranger’* impliquerait des opérations à l'étranger, mais ça s'approche d'un exemple cité et je suis curieux).

Comment: @Feelew Pour moi  **à** implique qu'ils y sont en ce moment, si **de** peut être ambigu dans certains contextes, **à** ne l'est pas. Par contre bien sûr l'emploi du mon *compatriote* enlève toute ambiguïté quant à la nationalité des personnes en question.

Comment: Est-ce que **à** impliquerait qu'ils y sont, mais pas forcément qu'ils y demeurent (en voyage, par exemple), et **de** impliquerait qu'ils y demeurent sans qu'ils y soient forcément maintenant (ils pourraient être en visite dans la mère-patrie en ce moment)?

Comment: @Feelew pour moi ,**à** ne dit rien sur leur lieu de résidence habituel, uniquement sur le moment en question. Je n'arrive pas à l'opposer à **de** qui pour moi ne résiste pas à toute ambiguïté.

Answer (score 0):

Vos 2 phrases françaises sont aussi ambiguës que les phrases (your 2 sentences are as ambiguous as) :

```
Our patients from a foreign country...   
Our foreign patients...
```

Levez donc l’ambiguïté comme vous le faites en anglais, par exemple (you can simply say in french what you said in english):

> Nos patients non japonais qui viennent de l'étranger <strike>dans le
>   seul but de</strike> pour se faire soigner ...

Comment: «Nos patients non japonais qui viennent de l'étranger dans le seul but de se faire soigner» est en effet très clair. Ça a seulement le défaut d'être un peu rugueux. Les japonais sont un peuple tellement poli (j'en sais quelque chose, pour avoir passé une décennie dans une ville qui accueille plus que sa population annuellement en touristes japonais), il serait dommage qu'il se donnât une image aussi brutale.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec vous pour le coté rugueux. Je me suis basé sur la phrase donnée par Alone-zee : "patients who come from abroad to Japan *solely for the purpose* of seeking treatment at our clinic". Ma traduction ne me semble pas plus rugueuse que sa version anglaise. Je me désole des 2 versions mais j'ai voulu respecter la volonté, peut-être rugueuse, de Alone-zee. Voyez, j'ai ajouté "peut-être" dans ma dernière phrase. Je ne voudrais pas lui faire offense.

Comment: Je crois que Alone-Zee cherchait à expliciter ce que le message devait transmettre, non à donner un modèle à répliquer. Il veut un message qui s'adresse sans ambiguïté aux étrangers venus visiter la clinique, sans forcément le dire aussi crûment. Mais à la lecture de votre commentaire, je vois que plusieurs lectures étaient possibles de son message. Je crois néanmoins que vous devriez réévaluer votre interprétation. Le tout soumis très respectueusement et sans arrière-pensée à votre attention. :)

Comment: OK, "pour se faire soigner".

Answer (score 0):

Your second English phrase has a nuance that (2) in French doesn't: "who already live in Japan".

The concept of *resident* comes to mind (same word in French and English).

> Nos patients étrangers résidents japonais

or

> Nos patients étrangers résidant au Japon

(from *résider*)

I think that this vs.

> Certains de nos patients venus de l'étranger [pour des soins]

pretty much covers the two mutually exclusive situations you want to contrast.